# Include Css file in user control

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I've got a popup which is in a user control and then registered inthe header of my aspx page. In the header I've indluded the javascript for the pop up to function and this works well. However, I've also got a css file included which doesn't seem to get applied. I've tried to include the css file in the user control like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("../css/shared.css") %>" />
```

But it didn't work. Any suggestions how I can include the css file? Am I right in assuming I have to do this in the user control?

Comment: Put ~ in css file path

Comment: getting this error when I do that : CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `..` and Add `~` in css path.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/css/shared.css") %>" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but still nothing happening

Comment: yeah I made sure. Any idea why it is able to load the js from the header but not the css?

Comment: Mostly it will work.I think you just check the path.Remove single quotes and add this line href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/css/shared.css") %>'

Comment: thanls, this did work even though I found that the actually issue was in my control mark up!